# Extending class in dart for existing data models

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I'm building an app for scanning fruits and vegetables and storing the data in firestore where the data are parameters for that particular commodity.

Currently all the data is kept under 'scans' collection. The documents contain parameters like:

```
"userID": "Dummy",
"scanName": "0",
"commmodity": "Apples",
"result": {"color": "bright red", "size": small}
```

and another like:

```
"userID": "Dummy",
"scanName": "1",
"commmodity": "Grapes",
"result": {"color": "black", "number": 40}
```

As you can see, the parameters are not the same for "result".

I want to understand how to implement this in the OOP paradigm, meaning my model class:

```
class ScanData {
    String? userID;
    String? scanName;
    dynamic result;
    String? commodity;

    ScanData({this.userID, this.scanName, this.result, this.commodity});

    ScanData.fromMap(Map json){
    return ScanData(
      userID: json['userID'],
      scanName: json['scanName'],
      result: json['result'],
      commodity: json['commodity']
    );
  }
}

class Apples{
    String? color;
    double? size;

    Apples({this.color, this.size});

    Apples.fromMap(Map json){
    return Apples(
      color: json['color'],
      size: json['size'],
    );
  }
}

class Grapes{
    String? color;
    double? number;

    Grapes({this.color, this.number});

    Grapes.fromMap(Map json){
    return Apple(
      color: json['color'],
      number: json['number'],
    );
  }
}
```

Here, I want the ScanData class to infer the type of commodity and respectively return the type of data that is relevant ie. dynamic result becomes Apples or Grapes according to the commodity.

These are my questions:

1. Is it better to create separate model classes for each type of
   ScanData like AppleScanData and GrapeScanData or is it better to
   extend the apple and grape class to a class commodity that deals
   with that?
2. If so, can anyone share an example?

Answer (score 0):

According to the code you would like to implement, the method of obtaining the attributes and characteristics of another class in Dart is termed as inheritance. It enables the creation of a new class from an existing one. It is the most fundamental OOPs idea (*Object-Oriented programming system*), the way you wanted to implement.

In the new class, we can reuse all the prior classes' behavior and characteristics.

**Parent Class** - A superclass or parent class is a class that is inherited by another class. A base class is another name for it.

**Child Class** - A child class is a class that inherits properties from another class. It's also known as a subclass or derived class.

There are different types of inheritance:

- Single inheritance.
- Multiple inheritance.
- Multilevel inheritance.
- Hierarchical inheritance.

You can find this documentation in [Dart Inheritance](https://www.javatpoint.com/dart-inheritance).

The example of the syntax is:

```
class child_class extends parent_class {  
    //body of child class  
}
```

Example of a single level inheritance:

```
class apple{    
      void red()  
         {  
            print("The apple is red");  
          }  
   }    
      // Inherits the super class  
class grapes extends apple{    
         //child class function  
         void black(){  
             print("Grapes are black");  
                 }            
}  
void main() {  
      // Creating object of the child class  
      grapes g=new grapes();    
      g.speak();    
      g.fly();    
}
```

Now here is also an “example” to [extending a class](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#extending-a-class):

Use extends to create a subclass, and super to refer to the superclass:

```
class Television {
  void turnOn() {
    _illuminateDisplay();
    _activateIrSensor();
  }
  // ···
}

class SmartTelevision extends Television {
  void turnOn() {
    super.turnOn();
    _bootNetworkInterface();
    _initializeMemory();
    _upgradeApps();
  }
  // ···
}
```